# Remapping bad sectors from sectors not in the spare sector pool

Tags: sd-card, bad-sectors, sectors

For common flash controllers what happens when the spare-sector pool runs out and a bad-sector is found? Will a flash controller (any form factor) remap failing sectors to non-allocated sectors in the main block? Will it just stop attempting to remap sectors and give undefined return?

Also, how can you check the number of sectors in a spare sector pool? I am only familiar with certain controllers sending a percentage of life remaining (I assume its based off how much of the spare pool has been used). Is there a common number of sectors to include in this pool? A percentage or flat amount?

I am trying to do a theoretical calculation for the life of a microsd card assuming the writes/sec, write size, sector size, and sector write/cycle limit.